# Clear only cells containing formulas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need a VBA code that clears only cells containing formulas and skip cells containing values in a given Excel Worksheet. 
I have the following Code:

```
Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MATRIX").Range("C2:AU10000")
    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.Hyperlinks = .Hyperlinks Then
            cl.ClearContents
        End If
    Next cl
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach, please:

```
If cl.HasFormula Then
       cl.ClearContents
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be the quickest way

```
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 2):

### HasFormula vs SpecialCells(xlTypeCellTypeFormulas)

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveHasFormula()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MATRIX").Range("C2:AU10000")
    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.HasFormula Then cl.ClearContents
    Next cl
End Sub

Sub RemoveSpecialCells()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MATRIX").Range("C2:AU10000")
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Delete formulae via a range's XML structure**

For the sake of the art and in order to complete the above solutions I demonstrate a rather unknown approach using a range's **xml spreadsheet value** (so called "`.Value(11)`"):

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheet1.Range("a11:b14")
'a) Get range data as xml spreadsheet value
    Dim s As String: s = rng.value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet) ' //or: s = rng.Value(11)
'b) delete formulae and write data back to range
    ClearFormulae s                                            ' call sub changing s (By Reference)
    rng.value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet) = s
End Sub
```

```
Sub ClearFormulae(s)
'Purpose: delete formulae in xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet contents of a given range
'Author : https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
'Date   : 2020-07-18
'[1]Set xml document to memory
    Dim xDoc As Object: Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
'[2]Add namespaces.
    xDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
        "xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' " & _
        "xmlns:ht='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'"

'[3]Load cells with formulae into xml document.
If xDoc.LoadXML(s) Then         ' load wellformed string content
    Dim cell As Object, cells As Object
    Set cells = xDoc.SelectNodes("//ss:Cell[@ss:Formula]")  ' XPath using namespace prefixes
    For Each cell In cells
        cell.RemoveAttribute ("ss:Formula")
        cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data/@ss:Type").Text = "String"
        cell.SelectSingleNode("ss:Data").Text = ""
    Next cell
    '[4] return xml as string content
    s = xDoc.XML
End If

End Sub
```

**Further hint to Example call**

Instead of replacing the same range, you can also copy the whole data set (including formats) to another sheet via:

```
    Sheet2.Range("D2").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).value(11) = s
```

**Caveat**

As @ChrisNeilson pointed out,
*"this can also gives unexpected results in some circumstances
where the range being processed by ClearFormulae includes some cells
that contain formula referring to cells* **outside** *the range being processed".*

**Testing `Value(11)` against other solutions**

Testing with a 20% formula rate (in a double column range) shows that the **`SpecialCells`** approach (posted by *@Storax* and *@VBasic2008*) starts *extremely fast*, but looses against my **`Value(11)`** approach as soon as the data range exceeds ~ 115,100 rows.

The `HasFormula` solution (*@FaneDuru*) seems to be restricted to smaller ranges getting soon time consuming at ranges over 10000 rows.

[image: Test results]

Comment: It respects the "principle" why simple if complicated is possible, but interesting approach... :) Voted it up.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback; it 's correct that the xml syntax may seem complicated... I always try to explore *unconventional* methods and to make them work in order to learn from them. So *a priori* the focus isn't laid upon simplicity. - FYI recently tested data edited just now show some possibliy unexpected results. @FaneDuru

Comment: @t.m. this has the unfortunate side effect of leaving the ex-formula cells containing an empty string, rather than truely Empty (the other methods correctly clear the formula cells).  This can be fixed by replacing the contents of your `For` loop with `cell.ParentNode.RemoveChild cell`

Comment: @t.m. this can also gives unexpected results in some circumstances where the range being processed by `ClearFormulea` includes some cells that contain formula referring to cells outside the range being processed (example if `A1` = `1`, `B1` = `=D1`, `D1` = `2`, run `ClearFormulea` on `A1:B1` results in `A1` = `1`, `B1` = `2`)

Comment: @chrisneilsen - thanks for your valuable hints: (1) IMO a true `Empty`ing could rather be executed on the `<Data>` **childNode**, otherwise I'd have to re-index all following neighbour nodes of `cell` after complete cell deletion. (2) I learnt that references to cells outside the range are interpreted as pure number type data without any trace to a possible formula. - Most appreciated, will edit a caveat :-)